# Cast is forced when using generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, casting

I wrote my own Stack class (for the relevant code, see below). In the `next()`-method I am forced to cast `current.item` to `Item`, but I do not know why. The type of `current.item` should already be `Item` and thus casting should not be necessary - but if I do not cast it, I get an error.

```
public class Stack<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

  private class Node {
      Item item;
      Node next;
  }

  private Node first= null;

  public Iterator<Item> iterator() { return new StackIterator(); }

  private class StackIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item> {
    private Node current = first;

    public Item next(){
        Item item = (Item)current.item;
        current = current.next;
        return item;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error ?

Comment: @SanketPipariya:Type mismatch : can not convert from Item to Item

Comment: @Override on the next method in the StackIterator should resolve ur problem..

Comment: @SamDJava: That didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type parameter from `StackIterator<Item>` hides the type `Item`, which is introduced in the definition of the `Stack<Item>` class.

This is why you need to do a cast (or to add a `@SuppressWarnings("hiding")` annotation).

In order to get rid of the warning, just remove the duplicated type:

```
private class StackIterator implements Iterator<Item> {

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You were using `<Item>` as a type parameter on both `Stack` and `StackIterator`, whereas what you really want to do is have `StackIterator` without a parameter and just state that it implements `Iterator<Item>`:

```
    private class StackIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
        private Node current = first;

        @Override
        public Item next() {
            Item item = current.item; // no need to cast now
            current = current.next;
            return item;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your class `StackIterator` is an inner class of `Stack`. That especially means that it is not *static*. Therefore it already knows about the type parameter `Item`.

You are doing the mistake of making the `StackIterator` having its own type parameter `Item`. This shadows the type parameter of the outer class.

So, simply remove the type parameter from `StackIterator`:

```
public class Stack<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
    private class Node {
        Item item;
        Node next;
    }

    private Node first = null;

    @Override
    public Iterator<Item> iterator() { return new StackIterator(); }

    private class StackIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
        private Node current = Stack.this.first;

        @Override
        public Item next() {
            Item item = this.current.item;
            this.current = this.current.next;
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `<Item>` in `StackIterator` to be the same type as the enclosing `<Item>` associated with `Stack`, remove the declaration of `<Item>` in `StackIterator`.

If you want the `<Item>` in `StackIterator` to be different than the enclosing `<Item>` associated with `Stack`, but you want to be able to access properties of the parent `Stack`, rename `<Item>` to something else.